# why pointer is placed with function in c ++?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

hello every one i was doing a C++ problem and found help on internet but one function confuse m that why we use pointer with function can any one explain me i am beginner in programming

```
char * replace_char( char *s, char source = 'a', char substitution = 'e' )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        if ( *s == source ) *s = substitution;
        replace_char( s + 1, source, substitution );
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: `s` is a parameter pointing to characters, probably the input to be processed. The function returns a pointer to characters, too. Not so easy to guess what it is pointing to, but probably a copy of the input, with replaced characters. Read the description of what the function does. Or maybe you already know, because you found it when searching for a specific behaviour.

Comment: Or to put it differently, it is unclear why you wonder about the pointer. What is it about a pointer parameter or return value that makes you wonder? Did you expect something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: As you can see, the return value is ignored by the author, too. The function, even its API, seems inefficiently designed. It is by the way a recursive function. Read up on recursion to understand. Doing something recursively which can easily be done iteratively is what makes the function inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function will return the same character pointer as the variable input "char* s"
Functions can return pointers to point to the start of an array.

edit: the function can also be written like this:

```
//This function will return an integer to indicate the number of replaced characters
int replace_char( char *sourcePtr, char source = 'a', char substitution = 'e' )
{
    int NrOfReplaced = 0;
    for(int i = 0; sourcePtr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ( sourcePtr[i] == source )
        {
            sourcePtr[i] = substitution;
            NrOfReplaced++;
        }
    }
    return NrOfReplaced;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is a data type and can be returned from a function just like any other data type (int, float, double...). In your case pointer to char represent a string, c-style string (which is basically the same as char[]). The function returns a pointer (the address) to the first element of the array